# Python - Use csv or Pandas to append to OR create new column

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv that looks like this:

```
identifier1, identifier2,
1.1        , 1.2
2.3        , 4.4
```

and a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{'identifier1':'3.3', 'identifier2':'2.3', 'identifier3':'1.6'}
```

I want to update this csv with this dictionary such that columns with the same identifiers are appended to and a column is created for new identifiers.

```
identifier1, identifier2, identifier3
1.1        , 1.2        , 1.6
2.3        , 4.4        ,
3.3        , 2.3        ,
```

Forgot to mention I've never really used pandas or csv, so some patience may be required here.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you read the [pandas tutorial](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/tutorials.html)?

Comment: `df.append(pd.Series(dictionary),True)` should solve your issue

Comment: @Alex, just to follow up on this, I have read the pandas tutorial, but what I wanted wasn't in there. I understand responding to newer people can get tedious, but next time if you could also offer a solution instead of a rhetorical question, I think that would have been more instructive and it certainly would have helped me more.

Comment: @TimBernstein For stackoverflow (and stackexchange generally) solutions are posted separately from the question. [Comments](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) can be used to (among other things) "Add relevant but minor or transient information to a post ..." e.g. an intro tutorial for someone who has "... never really used pandas ...".